# Displaying Images in a TableLayout properly in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, imageview, tablelayout

I've got the problem, that my images are not shrunken~ correctly in the Tablelayout that I've created programmatically.

[This is what I'm currently getting](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/4835/unled1u.gif).

and here's my code:

```
final TableLayout grd_overview = (TableLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.tbl_overview);
grd_overview.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1,  R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1,R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1, R.drawable.memory_2, R.drawable.memory_1};

int x = 0;
for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {

    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
            iv.setImageResource(mThumbIds[x]);
            tr.addView(iv);
            x++;
        }
    grd_overview.addView(tr);            
}
```

XML:

```
<TableLayout
      android:id="@+id/tbl_overview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I've got no idea how to shrink the rows that all `ImageView`s fit together perfectly. The images on the screenshot at the bottom are just smaller than they should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following line of code after initializing each `ImageView` inside the `for` cycle:

```
iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Or select the type of scaling that best fits your needs.

You can read more about [ScaleTypes here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html), and also about [scaling matrice algorithms](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.ScaleToFit.html#CENTER), eg. what this `FIT_CENTER` does.

Comment: thanks :) FIT_CENTER didnt work well, so I used FIT_XY. This one just made the images fit the X and Y axis. Though (the original pictures are squarish) the new pictures got rectangularly. The most bottom pictures took up the remaining space. The new problem is: How can I get the Tableview's height as high as the display's width?

Comment: nevermind, gonna make a new thread, after I tryed figuring this one out

Comment: This is what the `FIT_XY` should do (strech the second rectangle to match the first one). On the other hand, you can get the display's width in pixels using the `DisplayMetrics`: `getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels`.